# Does a bijective map from $(−π,π)→\mathbb R$ exist?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble proving that $\mathbb R$ is equinumerous to $(-π,π)$. I'm think about using a trigonometric function such as $\cos$ or $\sin$, but there are between the interval of $(0,1)$. Could someone help me define a bijective map from $(−π,π)→\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a trigonometric function such as $\tan$, although you must first divide the number by $2$ to instead get $\tan$ applied to a number in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: That's very clever! Thank you. I'll accept your answer in a few :-)

Answer (score 6):

For any open interval $(a,b)$, you can use:

$$f(x) = \frac{x -(a+b)/2}{(x-a)(x-b)}$$